# How can I get the "SelfActor" in OnBeginActorOverlap?

Tags: c++, collision-detection, unreal-4

The signature it takes is

```
void ( AActor* OtherActor )
```

However, The actor that is handling this event is not involved in the overlap. How can I access the actor that owns this delegate? Assuming I can't store a reference to this elsewhere. Is there another delegate that takes that parameter? Is this reference stored in OtherActor somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

Irritatingly, I don't believe there isn't a simple way (which is why most events in other frameworks have a `sender` parameter...). Instead, one way I've worked around is:

Bind to the collision event inside the actor that has the `UPrimitiveComponent` you want to listen to.

[Create an event](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Programming/UnrealArchitecture/Delegates/Events/index.html) in that actor that others can subscribe to. But this event has the signature `void (AActor* OtherActor, AActor* Sender)`.

When the first event is triggered, simply fire the other event, filling in `this` as the second parameter.

This also works in BP using event dispatchers.

Comment: This workaround is a crap, but I'm not saying that you did any wrong, I mean Unreal should definitely add a `sender`. By the way, I also uses this workaround now...

Answer (score 0):

The actor that is firing the event is the current instance:

(this-> )  Will get you the actor that is firing the event.

(OtherActor-> )  Will get you the actor that it collided with.

Comment: Like I said, the actor that is handling the event has nothing to do with the overlap.

Comment: How does it have nothing to do with the overlap? It has to overlap with something in order to fire the delegate.